# Trying to get a memory stream from a pdfstamper into a pdfreader but getting: "PDF startxref not found"

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm writing an app in c# that fills a bunch of pdf forms, concatenates them then puts in some page numbers.  I'm having difficulty with the memorystream result from the pdfstamper.  If I change the memorystream to a filestream it works fine but I don't want to use the filesystem.  I've created the following code snippet that reproduces my error:

```
    public static void TestStreams(string filepath)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
        //The error is in the following line
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(result);
    }
```

The error is:

```
iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: PDF startxref not found.
  Source=itextsharp
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot one line:

```
public static void TestStreams(string filepath) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    stamper.Close();
    byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
    //The error is in the following line
    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(result);
}
```

When you do `ms.ToArray()` without first closing the `stamper`, you have an incomplete PDF. The PDF starts with `%PDF-`, but there's no `%%EOF`, no trailer, no catalog. An incomplete PDF can't be read by `PdfReader`.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Should have come to stackoverflow sooner.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie 2 years later, I stumbled upon this post as I was having the same issue as the OP. This fixed my problem as well. Thank you very much, +1 from me.