# Failed to load pdf document in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Hi This is my C# code :

```
Byte[] bytes;

int orderID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

var templateData = ordersBL.GetTemplateDetails(orderID);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{

using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10))
{
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
foreach (var temp in templateData.ToList())
{

string message = temp.Message;
string tempimage = Convert.ToBase64String(temp.logo);
string base64 = tempimage;
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
if (image.Height > image.Width)
{
float percentage = 0.0f;
percentage = 700 / image.Height;
image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
}
else

{

float percentage = 0.0f;
percentage = 140 / image.Width;
image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
}

if (!document.IsOpen())
{

document.Open();
}
document.Add(image);
using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document))
{

using (var sr = new StringReader(message))
{


htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
}
}
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.SpacingBefore = 10;
paragraph.SpacingAfter = 10;
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
// paragraph.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12f, BaseColor.GREEN);

document.Add(paragraph);
document.NewPage();
}
bytes = ms.ToArray();
document.Close();

}
}
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
string pdfName = "User";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfName + ".pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
Response.Close();
Response.Flush();
}
```

Pdf is downloaded but it shows failed to load pdf document.

Failed to load pdf document in c#

I didn't find where I mistake in code.

Please give me correct code

Thanks.

Comment: Your `End` `Close` `Flush` code won't work like that. Please read: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation/ 
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816194/use-of-response-flush-before-response-end

Answer (score 4):

You are not creating a complete PDF file. Please take a look at my answer to the question [Trying to get a memory stream from a pdfstamper into a pdfreader but getting: "PDF startxref not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745333)

A PDF document is finalized when you close it:

```
document.Close();
```

The PDF is not complete *before* you do this.

However, you ask the `MemoryStream` *before* you close the document:

```
bytes = ms.ToArray();
document.Close();
```

This means that `bytes` doesn't contain the complete PDF.

Moreover, you are using `HTMLWorker`. That class has been abandoned many years ago, please read the intro of the [documentation about XML Worker](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml).

It's possible that `HTMLWorker` implicitly closes the `document` object (I don't remember, as I said: `HTMLWorker` is no longer used). In that case, the code that adds the `paragraph` object to the document will throw an exception saying that the document is closed and that you can no longer add any extra content.

Answer (score 1):

@shivakumar, Please try like this sample and change it for your data.

```
Byte[] bytes = ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"D:\Test\Sample1.png"));
         //Converted Image to byte[] 

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
            document.Open();     
            byte[] imageBytes = bytes;
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
            if (image.Height > image.Width)
            {
                float percentage = 0.0f;
                percentage = 700 / image.Height;
                image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
            }
            else
            {

                float percentage = 0.0f;
                percentage = 140 / image.Width;
                image.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
            }

            if (!document.IsOpen())
            {

                document.Open();
            }
            document.Add(image);
            var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            string message="hi";
            using (var sr = new StringReader(message))
            {


                htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
            }

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            document.Close();
        }
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        string pdfName = "User";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfName + ".pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
        Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid stream containing a PDF, and you're getting "Failed to Load PDF Document" from Chrome, this will definitely cause a problem:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfName + ".pdf");
```

'attachment' specifically tells the browser *not* display this document in-browser, but rather to send the file directly. And I just spent a few hours learning that Chrome's PDF viewer chokes in that situation, probably by design!

Try this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfName + ".pdf");
```

More: [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)